# wordpress folder no longer working after changing to ssl

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have a wordpress site and I made a folder directory to hold all my pdf documents that I wanted people to click a link and download all of this worked fine until I changed my site over to ssl now I am getting 500 internal server error. what I have done is I changed the web.config file because I am on IIS to route all http to https. I changed the wp-config.php to this

```
define('WP_HOME',       "https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/");
define('WP_SITEURL',    "https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/");
```

I also made sure all urls are re-configured to https instead of http any help would be greatly apperciated I did see this in the wp-config.php but I cant find anywhere to say I need to change this also

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST',
```

thank you in advance for any help.

here is my rule in my web.config

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
              <rule name="WordPress:" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                  <match url="*"/>
                      <conditions>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                      </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
              </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude everything looks good on your side with your configuration I would double check your sub folders directory and see if some how there is a second web.config in that directory overwriting your rules from your root web.config.

Comment: I feel like an idiot thank you for your response that was exactly the problem omg!!!